# Is it possible to use ST Link USB for UART Communication?

Tags: stm32, uart

I am using STM32L1 Series Discovery board and want to do uART communication via same UART port that is Used for Embedded ST Link V2

[image] .

Embedded ST Link uses USART1 of STM32L100CT6 and Mini USB is connected to my PC. Refer following fig.

```
PA9 Pin  as USART1_Tx of STM31L100CT6
PA10 Pin as USART1_Rx of STM31L100CT6
```

I also connected JP1 that is provided on the board so now main problem with this is that I didn't find COM port !!!

Is it possible to use ST Link USB for UART Communication ?

Comment: "So is it possible to use ST Link USB for UART Communication ?" - Nope.

Comment: The STM boards that support the arm mbed system do just this so it is in theory possible with the correct drivers installed on the PC. Whether the st-link firmware on that specific board supports it or not is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible (without a hardware modification, and custom ST-Link firmware). PA9 and PA10 are connected to the LCD display and the side headers, but not connected in any way to the onboard ST-Link.

You can however do that with a Nucleo board, where PA2 and PA3 (USART2) of the target controller are connected to the onboard USB controller, but of course it doesn't have that nice LCD display.

Comment: this is not true, stlink supports serial communication with host via usart, and most boards provide it. since you have what, 6 uart peripherals. mine on discovery is uart 3.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Yes, but some of the low-cost ST-Link adapters don't route it out to the connector. In such cases, it will need a modification.

Answer (score 2):

If what you really need is a "serial terminal" you can [convert the ST link to J-Link](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/) and use Segger RTT. It works like a serial terminal, but over JTAG.

Answer (score 1):

It needs stllinl 2.1 to work. And it needs the user tx rx pins being routed out.

More details here. https://dannyelectronics.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/uart-debugging-over-st-link-v2-1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ST-LINK V2 clone and are willing to make a minor hardware modification and sacrifice a 5V output rail, serial debugging is definitely doable as either UART or SWO.

Disconnect the trace leading to the 5V pin, which isolates it from the power rail by scraping a small channel across it with a sharp pin or blade. Next, solder a bodge wire from pin PA1O on the MCU to the now disconnected 5V rail. A resistor from 22V to 100V can be added for protection, but may not be necessary. Pay careful attention to the pins arrangements. They often differ even between two nearly identical-looking boards.

The following two links detail the hardware modification:
https://lujji.github.io/blog/stlink-clone-trace/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqrUAzjJ0tw