# Add serial interface to ST-link clone

Tags: stm32, serial, debugging, st-link

I recently started studying STM32 microcontrollers (BluePill STM32F103 dev board + ST-link V2 clone). I was wondering if it is possible to add serial communication to ST-Link clone?

From what I understood, those clones are copied form ST-link schematic of official Nucleo boards. The ST-link on Nucleo boards is build with STM32F103CBT6 and pins 12 and 13 (PA_2 and PA_3) are used as TX and RX for serial communication with target microcontroller (and connects to PA_2 and PA_3 pins of targer). See [page 65 of official Nucleo documentation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf)

Meanwhile, on ST-link clones those pins are floating and not connected to anything

[image: St-Link clone which I have]

If I solder 2 wires to pins 12 and 13 of STM32 microcontroller on ST-link clone, would I be able to use those for serial communication with target microcontroller on BluePill board (PA_10 and PA_9 or PA_2 and PA_3)?

**UPDATE:**

Looks like specifically this ST-link clone is made based on schematics of ST-link on old Discovery boards like this:
[image: ST-Link on Discovery boards]
In this "configuration" in can't be converted into ST-Link with Serial port feature, since this feature (as Virtual Com port) was added in ST-Link V2.1 on Nucleo boards and has another schematic:
[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**

The topic is not relevant anymore. Recently STMicroelectronics released STLink V3 Mini with very affordable price and same functionality (SWD + VCP) which I bought.
Now it can be bought at about [$10](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STLINK-V3MINI/497-19530-ND/10266291)

Comment: What this link is used for? In any case. these "clones" are not necessarily having the same firmware as the original. So it might be the case that there is no support for it in the firmware (whatever this support is for..).

Comment: ST-link is programming/debugging tool for STM32 microcontrollers. And they are compatible with official firmware for original ST-Link from STMicroelectronics.

Comment: Soldering wires onto pins won't do you any good unless the software on your ST-link clone supports those pins and emulates a serial port over USB. Do you have any reason to believe that it does? What does the documentation for your clone say?

Comment: @YehorPererva I know what ST-Link is. But I don't think the serial TX/RX are playing any role in programming.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ah, these are for virtual COM port. Got it.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321455/64158 says no, ST Link v2 doesn't have a USB-UART port

Comment: @MarcusMüller Some of the embedded variants of the ST-Link v2 support VCP. Convincing this one that it's on the right kind of board may be tricky, though.

Comment: If the VCP device isn't showing up on the host computer already (or at least in the descriptors), soldering wires won't do any good because the firmware you have in there does not support this.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - I can't find documentation for clone.

Comment: @duskwuff - looks like it is not a case with my clone. And, I think other problem is that my clone is made with STM32F101, meanwhile ST-Link from Nucleo is made with STM32F103

Comment: That's simple and was told here several times - if the pins are not connected, they have no use supported by the firmware. These clone makers are cutting costs as much as it is possible.

Comment: @YehorPererva Using a STM32F101 instead of a '103 is a common "hack" in cheap ST-Link devices. The silicon in the two parts is identical, and the USB transceiver usually works.

Comment: @duskwuff - I'm checking for traces and comparing with original ST-Link schematic on Nucleo boards. Looks like to enable the VCP, the microcontroller on ST-Link needs to provide the signal from pin 38 to start enumerating com-port. In my clone this pin is just floating. I think this is end of this "investigation"

Comment: @YehorPererva - no, that pin merely control the USB enumeration resistor to let the upgrade bootloader etc work (vs tying it permanently).   It is not a mode pin for the STLINK firmware to have or not have the VCP port.  That is rather determined by the firmware variant loaded.

Comment: Honestly it would be worth just sitting down and re-implementing an ST-LINK in open source form.  Most of the building blocks are there, but the ST-LINK scheme makes more efficient use of USB full speed than the published-source CMSIS-DAP one does, and it would be nice to have the VCP *without* the silly mass storage thing.  And we could drive whichever pin those cute little dongles erroneously wire the target reset to, rather than having to do micro surgery on each one...

Comment: Have you tried connecting pc13 to 3v3? It seems that pin is used to identify the version of the st link hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the binary code from the STLINK V2-1 STM32F103CB with ST Link Utility.

You will need a 128K version (103CBT6) of part so normal 64K Blue pill is not big enough.  I believe the mARM drop-folder transfer utility probably bloats the V2-1 code to requiring 128K.

I have also heard the firmware USB update will not work because of the USB bootloader having flash protection turned on for the V2-1.

You can get the STLINK V2 with SWO function on a 64K BluePill with the ST Link Utility firmware code download from a STLINK firmware updated Chinese clone.

You can also just cut the 5v runner and take over the connector 5v pins for SWO from uC pin 31 on a Chinese clone.  Need to have a fine tip soldering iron and a steady hand to solder the pin 31 connection wire without shorting to adjacent pins.

With the cost of a Nucleo64 ST32F103 with the STLINK V2-1 at less then $11 (Mouser) you have to think about whether it is worth the work.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have either a Blue Pill or one of the ST-Link 2 clones, I would just turn either one into a [Black Magic Probe](https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/wiki).

It integrates a GDB server so no other software is required.

There is a serial link available that will turn it into USB serial connection.  This link is not connected to the debug portion, so it can be used stand alone if you wish.

And it's open source.